# How to memorize a portion of string when it match a regex?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to memorize a part of a string when it match a regex like :

```
for line in my file:
    regex = re.compile(r'characters(textToSave)otherCharacters')
    # here I would like to memorise what's in parenthesis like somehow
    # portion = /1 (texToSave)
    # so then I could do:
    if regex.search(line):
       #do something with portion
```

(in perl for example we just have to say portion = $1)

Somebody have an idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that even in Perl. You need to actually *run* the regex search against a string to initialize a `$1` variable.

In Python, first, match it with `re.search`, and then you will be able to access the match data object:

```
import re
line = "characterstextToSaveotherCharacters"
regex = re.compile(r'characters(textToSave)otherCharacters')
matchObj = regex.search(line)
if matchObj:
    print(matchObj.group(1)) # Now, matchObj.group(1) contains textToSave
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fuU3Af)

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation. If I have two portion, I can't have two textToSave in parenthesis or can I ?

Comment: @H.eyXD you can have any number of parenthesis

Comment: Yes you can, and you can access them both using group, see [group for python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) or [group for python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group).

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Sorry, I was deep in thoughts about another question. Surely the 2 links provided by Xiflado are a must read for you to learn more about Python `re` module. Once you realize it is rather a poor replacement for a Perl regex, just intall [PyPi *regex* module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) and enjoy using regular expressions in Python,

Comment: @H.eyXD Glad it worked for you. Please also consider [upvoting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) if it turned out useful for you.